# Método PCA para feature selection - Como solucionar o erro raise Exception("Data must be 1-dimensional")?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Estou tentando implementar o método PCA para feature selection a partir das seguintes funções:

```
#Função que permitirá rankear as features mais importantes em um barhplot
def ranks_PCA (x_train, y_train, features_train, RESULT_PATH='Results'):
    print("\nMétodo PCA")

    pca = PCA(n_components=58)
    pca.fit_transform(x_train)

    imp_array = np.array(pca.components_)
    imp_order = imp_array.argsort()
    ranks = imp_order.argsort()

    # Plot PCA
    imp = pd.Series(pca.components_, index=x_train.columns)
    imp = imp.sort_values()

    imp.plot(kind="barh")
    plt.xlabel("Importance")
    plt.ylabel("Features")
    plt.title("Feature importance using PCA")
    # plt.show()
    plt.savefig(RESULT_PATH + '/ranks_DT.png', bbox_inches='tight')

    return ranks
```

---

```
#Função para predição das features dos dados de teste
def predict_PCA(x_test_sel, k_vetor, y_train):
    model = decomposition.PCA()
    model.fit(k_vetor, y_train)
    y_predict = model.predict(x_test_sel)
    return(y_predict)
```

---

```
#Função que calcula o ranking dos dados de treinamento
ranks4 = frk.ranks_PCA(x_train, y_train, features_train, RESULT_PATH)
```

Tenho dúvidas se essa implementação é correta para obter features mais importantes. Ao tentar executar este código, eu recebo o seguinte erro:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "feat_test.py", line 235, in
>   
>       'Results/PDBbind2018_F58_Delta_pKd')   File "feat_test.py", line 78, in run_experiment
>       ranks4 = frk.ranks_PCA(x_train, y_train, features_train, RESULT_PATH)   File "C:\Users\Patricia\Desktop\VT-58 -
>   Cópia\feature-importance\feature_rank_
>   ensemble\Scripts\feature_ranks.py", line 121, in ranks_PCA
>       imp = pd.Series(pca.components_, index=x_train.columns)   File "C:\Users\Patricia\Desktop\VT-58 -
>   Cópia\feature-importance\feature_rank_
>   ensemble\env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 305, in
>   **init**
>       data = sanitize_array(data, index, dtype, copy, raise_cast_failure=True)   File "C:\Users\Patricia\Desktop\VT-58 -
>   Cópia\feature-importance\feature_rank_
>   ensemble\env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\construction.py", line 482,
>   in saniti ze_array
>       raise Exception("Data must be 1-dimensional")

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

O atributo **components_** de [sklearn.decomposition.PCA](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html) retorna um array com shape igual à  (n_components, n_features). No seu caso (58, x.shape[0]).

Você está usando esse array para tentar criar um objeto do tipo [pandas.Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html), que aceita somente arrays de 1 dimensão.

O erro está em:

```py
imp = pd.Series(pca.components_, index=x_train.columns)
```

Se você quer plotar somente um componente, você deve escolher ele ou mudar o número de componentes do PCA para 1.